# P-Complete hashes, hashing to a larger set

Tags: hash, complexity

Historically hashes have been from a large set (say 256 characters) to a smaller set (256 bits).

Also, hash functions that are P-complete have no known parallel algorithm; they must be computed serially which ensures a certain amount of temporal cost in computing them.

Three questions:

1. What is the technical term for hashes that map to a larger set than the domain?
2. Are there any good P-complete hashes?
3. Are there any good P-complete hashes that map to a larger set?

Comment: Encoding the string into a Game of Life grid and playing K rounds is an example of a P-complete hash. There must be a better one out there.

Comment: Combining a hash with an iterated stream cipher should do the trick.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5061/are-there-secure-stream-ciphers-that-cannot-be-parallelized